# JCheckBox already checked but it says else statement

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I create Hospital Management System for School projects and I think i am at 35% of the system and here at Patient Registration where I struggle a lot here is the `JFrame1 I have at First Page

[First Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysAAf.png)

St First Page I have this Past Medical History and Review Symptoms with other options so if I don't check any of the `JCheckBox` controls including the None check box but I click the next Button it will pop up the option if you don't have any Past Medical History the codes like this

```
if(!jCheckBox1.isSelected() || !jCheckBox2.isSelected() || !jCheckBox3.isSelected() || !jCheckBox4.isSelected() || !jCheckBox5.isSelected() || !jCheckBox6.isSelected() || !jCheckBox7.isSelected() || !jCheckBox8.isSelected() || !jCheckBox9.isSelected() || !jCheckBox10.isSelected() || !jCheckBox11.isSelected() || !jCheckBox12.isSelected()|| !jCheckBox13.isSelected() || !jCheckBox14.isSelected() || !jCheckBox15.isSelected() || !jCheckBox16.isSelected() || !jCheckBox17.isSelected() || 
        !jCheckBox18.isSelected() || !jCheckBox19.isSelected() || !jCheckBox20.isSelected() || !jCheckBox21.isSelected() || !jCheckBox104.isSelected() || !jCheckBox102.isSelected() || !jCheckBox100.isSelected() || !jCheckBox98.isSelected() || !jCheckBox111.isSelected() || !jCheckBox94.isSelected() || !jCheckBox95.isSelected() || !jCheckBox99.isSelected() || !jCheckBox109.isSelected() || !jCheckBox112.isSelected() || !jCheckBox110.isSelected() || !jCheckBox97.isSelected() || 
        !jCheckBox107.isSelected() || !jCheckBox101.isSelected() || !jCheckBox106.isSelected() || !jCheckBox96.isSelected() || !jCheckBox105.isSelected() || !jCheckBox92.isSelected() || !jCheckBox103.isSelected()|| !jCheckBox93.isSelected() || !jCheckBox105.isSelected() || !jCheckBox115.isSelected() || !jCheckBox114.isSelected() || !jCheckBox113.isSelected() || !jCheckBox121.isSelected() || !jCheckBox120.isSelected() || !jCheckBox119.isSelected() || !jCheckBox118.isSelected() || 
        !jCheckBox117.isSelected()|| !jCheckBox116.isSelected() || !jCheckBox127.isSelected()){
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Medical History is empty","Error",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    int yesOrno = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "No medical History?", "Proceed",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(yesOrno == 0){
        jCheckBox127.setSelected(true);
        PARENTPANEL.removeAll();
        PARENTPANEL.add(ALLERGIES);
        PARENTPANEL.repaint();
        PARENTPANEL.revalidate();

        jCheckBox1.setEnabled(false);
        jCheckBox1.setSelected(false);

        jCheckBox2.setEnabled(false);
        jCheckBox2.setSelected(false);

        jCheckBox3.setEnabled(false);
        jCheckBox3.setSelected(false);
```

[JOptionPane Popup even when I already select one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pLFe.png)

I already checked the check boxes and click next but pop up always showed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing `||` into `&&` in the `if` clause may save you.